# How to add a captcha to NodeJS Express website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, recaptcha

I have a express router with the following line:

> ```
> router.post('/postComment/:id', postController.comment)
> ```

and the postController.js comment function where I create the comment object and executes create method from the Comment.js model:

```
> exports.comment = async function(req, res){
>         
>     var data = {
>         author: req.body.author,
>         message: req.body.message,
>         postId: req.session.postId.id
>     }
>     console.log(data)
> 
>     let comment = new Comments(data)
> 
>     comment.create().then(() => {
>         res.json(data)
>     }).catch(() => {
>         res.json([])
>     }) }
```

and the Comment.js model:

```js
const commentsCollection = require('../db').db().collection("Comments")
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID
const sanitizeHTML = require('sanitize-html')

let Comments = function(data) {
    this.data = data
    this.errors = []

}

Comments.prototype.cleanUp = function(){
    this.data = {
        author: sanitizeHTML(this.data.author),
        message: sanitizeHTML(this.data.message),
        createdDate: new Date(),
        postId: this.data.postId
    }
}

Comments.prototype.validate = function(){
    if (this.data.author == "") {this.errors.push("you must provide a author")}
    if (this.data.message == "") {this.errors.push("you must provide a message")}
}

Comments.prototype.create = function(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.cleanUp()
        this.validate()
        
        if(!this.errors.length){
            commentsCollection.insertOne(this.data).then(() => {
                resolve()
            }).catch(() => {
                this.errors.push("db problem")
                reject(this.errors)
            })
        } else {
            reject(this.errors)
        }
    })

}

Comments.viewCommentsByID = function(id){
        return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
            let comment = await commentsCollection.find({postId: id}).sort({createdDate: -1}).toArray({}, function(err, p){
            })

                resolve(comment)
                          
    })
}

module.exports = Comments
```

I want to add a captcha to my website so I can prevent bots from posting. I looked into Google captcha but couldn't get it to work properly. Everything is fine in my website, I just want to keep running as it but with the captcha.